# In a Jmeter script some of the samplers are being executed only once for each user, while it should run for 1 hr 30 min as defined

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I am running a Jmeter script. In the script there is only one transaction controller, in which I am having 10 Samplers (APIs). Script is designed to run with 90 users (Ramp up in 30 minutes) and 1 Hr in duration (excluding rampup time).

Once Test is completed, in the HTML report, I am seeing that 3 out of 10 APIs are executed only 90 times each (once per user), while rest of the APIs are running for whole 1 hr 30 minutes.

Can someone help me to get out of this please.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you share your jmx, please?   Have you inadvertently used the "Once Only Controller" for those 3 calls?   Please define "API".  Do you mean an HTML call?

Comment: No, I am not using Once Only Controller

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide a comprehensive answer without seeing:

1. Schematic view of your test plan, it can be generated via the relevant entry from the "Tools" menu:

   [image]

   the feature is available since [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/)
2. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (better with `DEBUG` logging enabled)

Also check whether

- There are any custom "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). The default action is `Continue`

  [image]
- There are any [Once Only Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
- There are any [If Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
- Action to be taken after a Sampler error - we are using Start next thread loop (Although there are no errors in the report).
- No Once only controllers used.
- No If Controllers used.

Comment: Also how can I send you the jmx or how to attach here. Could not found such option. Help really appreciated.